# Freemarker validates my spring form even though some values are blank

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, hibernate-validator

The validations are not working for model Address. The binding with person.address.email is working in ftl and java. However, when I submit the form with all the person details minus the address details, it still validates OK and goes to next page. Why is this happening? The binding seems to be good! Is something wrong with the controller?

Form:

```
<form action="processSignUp" method="POST" class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Personal Details</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <label for="email">Email (*)</label>
                            <@spring.bind 'person.email'/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.password'/>                           
                            <label for="password">Password (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.firstName'/>
                            <label for="firstName">First Name (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.lastName'/>
                            <label for="lastName">Last Name (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.mobile'/>
                            <label for="mobile">Mobile (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="mobile" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Address Details</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <label for="flatNo">Flat No. (*)</label>
                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.flatNo'/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="flatNo" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.locality'/>
                            <label for="locality">Locality (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="locality" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.area'/>
                            <label for="area">Area</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="area" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.city'/>
                            <label for="city">City (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.state'/>
                            <label for="state">State (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="state" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>

                            <@spring.bind 'person.address.pin'/>
                            <label for="pin">Pin (*)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pin" 
                                name="${spring.status.expression}" 
                                value="${spring.status.value?default("")}"/>
                            <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Do note that person.address.locality also does not seem to be working.

Snippet of my models:

```
    @Component
public class Person {
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
    @Positive
    private long mobile;
    @NotNull
    private Address address;


    @Component
public class Address {
    @NotBlank
    private String flatNo;
    @NotBlank
    private String locality;
    private String area;
    @NotBlank
    private String city;
    @NotBlank
    private String state;
    @Positive
    private int pin;
```

There is no change in the state if I submit the form - it goes to the expected view though - which is this page itself.

The controller code:

```
    @Controller
public final class SignUpController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/processSignUp")
    public ModelAndView processSignUpForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Person person, 
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("signup-form", "person", person);
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("signup-confirmation", "person", person);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker is **sevrer side** template engine, meaning it execute after submitted a form and reached sever side.

If you want to add on sumbit **client side** validation use javascript vanilla or framework as dojo, angular etc.

Also you shouldn't use `BindingResult bindingResult` when display page before submit. probably need to have 2 methods, for displaying page and processing form.

Comment: No! My code is written for server side validation only. But somehow it is performing validations even before I submit the form. May be I am missing something but I can't figure out.

Comment: You shouldn't use `BindingResult bindingResult` when display page before submit

Comment: I think that is the mistake I am making here. I will try this after office when I reach home. Will reply back! Thanks.

Comment: Ok! I am now able to make the validation work properly for person instance fields. However, it is still failing to validate Address fields. What am I doing wrong here? Updated the original post with new code.